# Mount HTTP directory on Raspbian?

Tags: filesystems, mount, raspbian, http

Is there a way to mount an HTTP resource in Raspbian (default Raspberry Pi OS)?  I have an HTTP server hosting music, and I would like to be able to have read-only filesystem access to that music on my Pi.  It's a simple HTTP directory, with directory listing enabled (aka, browse to http://192.168.1.60/music/ will give you a list of contents)

Also, I would prefer an answer that doesn't involve connecting my Pi to the internet, but instead gives a package/binary executable/something else that I can download offsite and bring there on a thumb drive.

Comment: What operating system is the HTTP host?

Comment: I haven't used it, but [httpfs](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/httpfs2) may be a possibility...

Comment: httpfs can only mount a single resource, not a directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a raspberry pi too and it works great for this type of thing, but I don't think so over http.

The best way to do this is to export a network share from the server.

- If the server runs Unix or Linux, then export as NFS (the unix native "Network File System").
- If the server runs Windows, then just share a drive readonly on the network.

With either of the above solutions, you can then mount the remote directory directly to your raspberry pi Raspian system.

Comment: OK, so how would I mount the SMB share from Windows?

Comment: And I'd rather not have to connect the Pi itself to the internet.

Comment: First you make an empty directory where it will show up, then use the Linux `mount` command to make it show up under your empty directory. Try this: `sudo mkdir /mnt/windowsharename; sudo mount -t cifs -o guest "//windowshost/sharename" /mnt/windowsharename`

Comment: Just curious, why don't you want to connect the Pi to the internet?

Comment: I've got parents.  It's a big hassle to get temporary internet.

Comment: And that command will let me mount the samba share without addons?

Comment: Try it and see what happens.  My pi doesn't have Raspbian on it right now so I can't test it for you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31211/discussion-between-robertl-and-daniel).

Comment: I'm trying it now